# How to search for files by extension and containing string within folder and subfolders?

Tags: node.js, search, filesystems

Is it possible to look for files of given extension by the containing string provided?

What should my approach be? For example the input is `txt` and `hello`, and the output will be list of all files containing the string `hello` with extension `txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You would write this in your terminal: `node main.js hello`

For a given directory it will search inside all subdirectories and all files for a text file with `hello`

Here is the code:

```js
const { readdirSync, readFileSync, lstatSync } = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


const getDir = source => {
  const results = readdirSync(source);
  results.forEach(function (result) {
    if (lstatSync(path.join(source, result))
      .isFile()) {
      if (readFileSync(path.join(source, result))
        .includes(argument) && path.extname(result)
        .toLowerCase() === extension) {
        console.log("Your string is is in file: ", result)
      }
    }
    else if (lstatSync(path.join(source, result))
      .isDirectory()) {
      getDir(path.join(source, result));
    }
  });
}
const dir = process.cwd();
const extension = '.txt'; //You can change the extension type here
let argument = process.argv[2];
getDir(dir);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use FileSystem to get the contents of a folder with the `readdir` method, this returns you an array of strings.

Let's say your working directory is a `src` file, in which there is a `files` folder that you want to read. Your script would look something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var files = fs.readdir('./files', (err, filenames) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    return filenames;
})
```

You can then separate your string using string methods. Let's say you want to have two variables, `fileName`and `fileExt`
You would use the `String.split(separator)` method, and use the `.` character as separator.

```
var files = // fs snippet above

for (file in files) {
    let fileComponents = file.split('.');

    let fileName = fileComponents[0];
    let fileExt = fileComponents[1];

    // You can run your code on the name, and extension of your file here.
}
```

This will not work for files containing multiple dots in their name. You will need extra work on the array to make sure `fileName` contains every string concatenated, separated by a `.` up until the final index of your `fileComponents` string

Comment: Doesn't answer question or explain anything on how to capture .txt files